# How can I edit menu Label (Description) in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, menu, topmenu

How can I edit menu Label(Description) in magento-2?

(i.e) I attached one screenshot. Here menu label was **SALE** .I want to change it **SALES**.
How to do this?
[image]

Comment: It is a category present on the site so just go to your backend > catalog > category & change the name as you want it

Comment: If it is not that then it can be the functionality of your theme so better do read the theme document properly & try to work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this from admin:

Catalog -> Categories -> click on particular category and update the name of category

then run indexing, flush cache and it will reflect on frontend. Attached is the screenshot for reference:
[image]